# Write a program that can read the file and display the number of students travelling by each mode of transport

Tags: python

Here is the scenario
A file “travel.txt” stores data about students as follows:

> First name, Surname, Programme, Means of transport.

Sample data is:

> John Farmer BScCse Bus
>
> Kevin Khan BScMCS Taxi
>
> Janet Zuber BScMIS Bus
>
> San Jacky BScAis PrivateCar
>
> Sarah Forceps BScIS PrivateCar

I want to  read the file and display the number of students traveling by each mode of transport in such a form:

> Taxi 1
>
> Bus 2
>
> PrivateCar 2

I've written the following code:

```
f1=open("travel.txt",'r')
line=f1.readline()
count1=0
count2=0
count3=0
while line!=" ":
    data=line.split()
    if data[3]=="Bus":
        count1=count1+1
    elif data[3]=="Taxi":
        count2=count2+1
    else:
        count3=count3+1
    line=f1.readline()
print("Taxi","\t",count1)
print("Bus","\t",count2)
print("Private Car","\t",count3)
f1.close()
```

But it is not working
could you help me

Comment: Exactly how is that code not working? Does it stop with an error--if so, show us the entire traceback. Does it give a wrong answer--if so, show us what the given answer was and ensure the wrongness of it is obvious.

Comment: actually it says this:list index out of range python but i've changed the loop to a for loop and used readlines as in the previous comment and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

Even though you might already have an answer here is is another method that is a bit simpler and can give you some other stats as well. You can read with `pandas` that automatically turns it into a `DataFrame`. This allows you to do some nice stuff with the data.

Assuming the data has spaces between them you can read the file like this:

```
import  pandas as pd
cols = ['Name', 'Surname', 'Degree', 'Transport']
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s', engine='python', header=None, names=cols)
```

It will give the following output:

```
    Name    Surname Degree  Transport
0   John    Farmer  BScCse  Bus
1   Kevin   Khan    BScMCS  Taxi
2   Janet   Zuber   BScMIS  Bus
3   San     Jacky   BScAis  PrivateCar
4   Sarah   Forceps BScIS   PrivateCar
```

you can then find out how many students use each transport method as follows:

```
data.groupby('Transport').count()['Name']
```

it will give you the following output:

```
Transport
Bus           2
PrivateCar    2
Taxi          1
```

there are other stats methods you can invoke such as `mean`. This makes your code and data more flexible compared to when you "hard" code a method.